# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7230272908: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe during post a value to server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ssl, retrofit2

I'm new to Android development. Could you please help me to solve my problem?

I just created a website to post some to-dos in a task, but the problem is it can't work properly.

This is the main error I found in the previous debugging:

```
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7230272908: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
```

Here is my debugging result:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: swipeFromBottom mIgnoring === false downY 163 mStatusBarHeight 54
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@2fdb836[EditorActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@2a8a50f, pkg = com.camrininfotech.mynotesapp
D/ViewRootImpl[EditorActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x722dbaa7c0
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/tech.mynotesap: constructJavaHashMap: start
    constructJavaHashMap: end
    sendCommonDcs: start
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: end
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
    constructJavaHashMap: start
    constructJavaHashMap: end
    sendCommonDcs: start
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: end
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    constructJavaHashMap: start
    constructJavaHashMap: end
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: start
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: end
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 16 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x72384dc000)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x72384dc000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/tech.mynotesap: constructJavaHashMap: start
W/tech.mynotesap: constructJavaHashMap: end
    sendCommonDcs: start
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: end
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
I/chatty: uid=10324(com.camrininfotech.mynotesapp) hostapp.com/... identical 1 line
D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
W/tech.mynotesap: constructJavaHashMap: start
    constructJavaHashMap: end
    sendCommonDcs: start
W/tech.mynotesap: sendCommonDcs: end
W/tech.mynotesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
D/WindowManager: removeViewLocked root=android.view.ViewRootImpl@853f2a9 view=DecorView@2fdb836[EditorActivity]
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x72384dc000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@2fdb836[EditorActivity]
I/InputTransport: Destroy ARC handle: 0x722dbaa7c0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: com.color.internal.widget.ColorToastLayout{ffaeb48 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #c0204f9 oppo:id/color_toast_layout}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@2a8a50f, pkg = com.camrininfotech.mynotesapp
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x721bcda2a0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x72384dc000)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x72384dc000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?